# Listview in Tablelayout in android

Tags: android, tablelayout

In my application i have 1 tablelayout,and 1 database.Now,i want to display that database content in a table layout.But it should look like a listview  because i have to show the entries one below the other.Is it possible to have listview inside table layout,also give some idea how to set the database entries in the corresponding listview in table layout.

Here is my XML structure:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingRight="2dip" >

        <TableRow>
            <TextView

                android_layout_span="2"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:text="Income" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView             
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Price:"/>

            <TextView


                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Price:" />

            <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Quantity:"/>

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/et_url"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Quantity:" />
        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show your data as a list/something like a list, then why you want to use table layout by making this a complex structure ??

Use your main list_view_layout in your activity which contains a list view. create another xml like list_item & use it in the adapter to show the data one by one. you may use table layout or the design as you wish in the list_item's layout.

You will get a better knowledge here at [**vogella.com**](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Just prepare your data set, create list & its adapter & then use the data in the adapter... thats it!!

Good Luck :-)

Comment: Thanks Soumyadip Das.But my requirement is i have to show the data in table format,because i have to show two list like structure side by side.